# Import - Export database with pgAdmin III

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Which are the steps to import and export a database using pgADMIN III? I followed the oficial tutorial and also some links in the Internet, but I don't get the correct result. THX!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use pgadmin for such things.
PG_dump, PG_restore are the proper simple tools to reliably backup and restore a database
simple example using Comand promt or using *.bat script

```
 pg_dump.exe --host localhost  -v --port 5432 -U postgres -Fc mydb > mydb.bak
 pg_restore.exe --host localhost --port 5434 --username postgres --dbname mydb mydb.bak
```

if you have installed postgresql on a windows machine, both executables are located in postgresql "bin" directory same as pgadmin.exe